# Associate operation to activity diagram

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uml, papyrus

How can I associate messages(operation calls) in a sequence diagram to its implementation(method)as an activity diagram?

`I am using Papyrus for modelling.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an indirect relationship possible in this case.

**A method** is typically defined in a class from a class diagram.

The same method is specified using an **activity diagram**.

The invocation of the method can be shown on a **sequence diagram**.

Class diagram gives kind of a structural back-up the the rest of the diagrams, and is highely recommendable to make one (if you don't have it already).

Comment: helpful answer@Aleks,Thank you so much for kind help

Answer (score 1):

The messaging in a sequence diagram are meant to become method invocations upon classes of objects. Activity diagrams are meant to be like a flow chart of the business processes.  The former will be very specific and detailed; the latter will be more generic and not so specific.

While they can be coincidentally related if you choose to model that way, since they are not by UML standards to be that directly related I don't think you'll find tooling that will do this for you.

You can read more here:

[UML Activity Diagram tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_activity_diagram.htm)

[UML Sequence Diagram tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_interaction_diagram.htm)